# Beside the block reward winner who will get most rewards from transaction fees?

Tags: block-reward, reward

We know the only winner will get the block reward. Besides the block reward, we know nodes/node clients get rewards from transaction fees. So do all node clients get the same rewards? or the ones who received direct transactions get more?

Answer (score 1):

Only the miner who mined the block gets the rewards: block reward and transaction gas fees. Others get nothing.

There is only one exception: if someone else manages to mine a block around the same time, but his block does not end up in the canonical chain, his block becomes an uncle block and he gets part of the block reward - but he doesn't get any gas fees, since the transactions in uncle blocks are not considered as executed.

Comment: what are the incentives for weak nodes running ethereum? I'm doubt about your answer. I think other nodes also did contribute in term of broadcasting transactions and verifying transactions

Comment: Yes, all nodes broadcast and verify transactions, but they do not get rewards for it. The incentive is usually to provide blockchain data for various applications, and not in the mining rewards. If you run your own node you don't need to rely on others' data